# why is store.getState() not updating my local state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

**heres my store...**
i've left out the imports for brevity, my problem is im getting state to update in the store using a dispatch from my component, but i cannot get that state to show im my component
console.log("store state", state); --> shows an array with my data

```
    const STUDENTS = "STUDENTS";
    
    const initialState = { students: [] };
    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      console.log("action", action);
      switch (action.type) {
        case STUDENTS:
          state = { ...state, students: action.students };
          console.log("store state", state); --> shows an array with my data
          return state;
      }
      return state;
    };
    
    const store = createStore(reducer);
    
    export default store;
```

*heres my component...*

```
   class StudentList extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = store.getState();
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        const studentRes = await axios.get("/api/students");
        //console.log("studentRes", studentRes);
        const studentData = studentRes.data;
        store.dispatch({ type: "STUDENTS", students: studentData });
        store.subscribe(() => this.setState(store.getState()));
      }
    
      async deleteStudent(student) {
        await axios.delete(`/api/students/${student.id}`);
        const students = this.state.students.filter(
          (notDeleted) => notDeleted.id !== student.id
        );
        this.setState({ students });
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log("student list state", this.state); --> shows up with an empty array
        const studentEls = this.state.students.map((student) => {
          return (
            <li key={student.id}>
              {student.name}, {student.year}
              <button onClick={() => this.deleteStudent(student)}>X</button>
            </li>
          );
        });
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Students</h1>
            <ul>{studentEls}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    render(<StudentList />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: Hi. For one, this is not how you use redux in React. You should be mapping state via react-redux connect (basically you never use the store directly in React). That said, I see how this can work by using the store directly, but in your case you are dispatching the action _before_ you have a store subscription. I bet your redux store state is indeed updated when you dispatch the action, but the copy of that store state isn't reflected in your React state (which are two separate things you are trying to keep in sync manually instead of letting redux do that for you)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I ended up using react-redux and got the app working. I was trying to learn redux on its own, it makes sense why subscribing after a dispatch wouldn't work.